# What is the simplest way to convert table Rows into XML and viceversa

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, row

I need to develop a sql server procedure which will convert table rows into xml and will transfer it to another stored procedure(Different server) through link server. On that server I have to take this xml data as input and again convert it into table rows. What will be the simplest and time efficient way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to use the XML datatype as a parameter in stored procedure on a linked server. You have to use `nvarchar(max)` and convert to XML in the stored procedure.

To create the XML you should use [FOR XML (SQL Server)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178107.aspx). `RAW` and `AUTO` is easy and if you need more control you could use `PATH`. I would stay away from `EXPLICIT`.

To shred the XML on the receiving side you should use [nodes() Method (xml Data Type)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188282.aspx) and [value() Method (xml Data Type)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178030.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Given that you are using SQL Server, you need only [append FOR XML](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178107.aspx) to your query.